# Grails. JSON. his methods?

Tags: json, grails

I was up all night looking for information on how to use `JSON` in `Grails`. And I found the information that in `JSON closure`, we can use only one method - `array` -  no other. is it true?

and next small question:

i find here: http://www.jiramot.info/mini-guide-to-rendering-json-with-grails example:

```
render(contentType:‘text/json’){
        collection{
                pair(name:‘value’)
                pair(name:‘value1′)
        }
}
```

Will be rendered as:

```
{collection:[{"name":"value"},{"name":"value1"}]
```

but when i try do it, i have this result:

```
{"collection":{"pair":{"name":"value1"}}}
```

What conclusion can we do?
i do some wrong or wrong example on site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [rendering JSON with Grails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304924/rendering-json-with-grails)

Comment: "If you have a different question, you should create a new"

Comment: sorry, I couldn't make the difference, since both questions didn't provide sufficient information about what's asked and what the problem is.

Comment: ok, maybe you're right. If necessary, I can remove the question. This is not a problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
render(contentType:‘text/json’){
        collection {
                array {
                   pair(name:"value")
                   pair(name:"value1")
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: what is this pair object? is it part of grails? If you look at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.7 XML and JSON Responses this tells you how to do it - i merely extrapolated from your example.

Comment: render(contentType:'text/json'){
                collection =array {
                   pair(name:"value")
                   pair(name:"value1")
                }

Answer (score 2):

JSON rendering in Grails is much easier...

```
def foobar = [ fooArray: [ 1, 2, 3 ], bar: [ b: "bbb", a: "aaa", r: "rrr" ] ]
render foobar as JSON
```

results in

```
{"fooArray":[1,2,3],"bar":{"b":"bbb","a":"aaa","r":"rrr"}}
```

Just create an appropriate Groovy structure and `render` it `as JSON`.