# How to create a json file from grails 2.4

Tags: mysql, json, grails

I am trying put pull data from a mysql database to put into a json file.  I have created my domain classes and controllers and have written data to the mysql database, but I'm stuck on getting it back out to create a json file.  Where/how do I do it? Help appreciated!

Comment: Have you [searched](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4311800/3959875) for similar questions?

Comment: Yes, but they don't help completely.  For example, where do I put the code to get it to display.  I have it here...

Comment: oops...hit enter too soon   package mytest

import grails.converters.*

class PlansController {

    def scaffold = Plans
 
 def jsonMethod = {
  def json = [Plans:[collection:[[name:‘value1′],[name:‘value2′]]]]
  render json as JSON
}

Comment: >package mytest
>import grails.converters.*
>class PlansController {
>    def scaffold = Plans 
> def jsonMethod = {
>  def json = [Plans:[collection:[[name:‘value1′],[name:‘value2′]]]]
>  render json as JSON
>}

Comment: Edit your question to include what you have already tried - comments section is not the place to paste code!

Comment: Do you really want to "create a json file" or do you want to produce JSON output in the user's browser? These are different things...

Comment: You are right....output to the browser.